# How to prevent App from Freezing after using URL LAUNCHER

Tags: flutter

please I need help with url_launcher.  I'm using one of its features- makePhoneCall. it freezes the app after I use it and comes back to the app.
it shows
D/MALI    (30528): gles_state_set_error_internal:76: [MALI] GLES error info: execution failed
D/MALI    (30528): gles_state_set_error_internal:75: [MALI] GLES ctx: 0x732a00c008, error code:0x505

```
String _phone = '02xxxxxxxx';

  Future<void>_makePhoneCall(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }


CircularCard(
  color: Colors.blueAccent,
  onPressed: (){
    setState(() {
     _makePhoneCall('tel:$_phone');
    });
  },
 text: 'Call to Order',
 iconData: FontAwesome.phone,
 iconColor: Colors.white,
),
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem rises in future as its returning promise.`

```
    String _phone = '02xxxxxxxx';

  _makePhoneCall(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }


CircularCard(
  color: Colors.blueAccent,
  onPressed: (){
    setState(() {
     _makePhoneCall('tel:$_phone');
    });
  },
 text: 'Call to Order',
 iconData: FontAwesome.phone,
 iconColor: Colors.white,
),
```

`